# how to join two table in spring boot JPA , iam getting error with my code

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, bidirectional

Hi i want to join my table from oracle how to join this table? i am using jpa For joining my table on spring boot. and this is my code :

```
package com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity.TblmFormManagement;


@Table(name = "TBLM_FORM")
@Entity
public class TblmForm{

    // @Column(name = "PKID")
    @Id
    private Long pkid;
    // @Column(name = "FORMCODE")
    private String formcode;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="TblmFormManagement")
    private TblmFormManagement tblmFormManagement;



    public TblmFormManagement getTblmFormManagement(){
        return tblmFormManagement;
    }

    public void setMapping(TblmFormManagement tblmFormManagement){
        this.tblmFormManagement=tblmFormManagement;
    }


    // @Column(name = "REPORTITEM")
    // private String reportitem;
    // @Column(name = "REPORTFIELD")
    // private String reportfield;

    public TblmForm() {
    }

    public Long getPkid() {
        return this.pkid;
    }

    public void setPkid(Long pkid) {
        this.pkid = pkid;
    }

    public String getFormcode() {
        return this.formcode;
    }

    public void setFormcode(String formcode) {
        this.formcode = formcode;
    }

    // public String getReportitem() {
    //     return this.reportitem;
    // }

    // public void setReportitem(String reportitem) {
    //     this.reportitem = reportitem;
    // }

    // public String getReportfield() {
    //     return this.reportfield;
    // }

    // public void setReportfield(String reportfield) {
    //     this.reportfield = reportfield;
    // }
    // @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tblmForm")
    // public Mapping getMapping() {
    //     return mapping;
    // }

    // public void setBook(Mapping mapping) {
    //     this.mapping = mapping;
    // }

}
```

My second entity :

```
package com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name = "TBLM_FORMMANAGEMENT")
@Entity
public class TblmFormManagement{


    // @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mapping")
    @Id
    private Long pkid;
    private String formcode;
    private String reportitem;
    private String reportfield;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pkid", nullable=true)
    private TblmForm tblmForm;


    public TblmForm getTblmForm() {
        return tblmForm;
    }

    public void setTblmForm(TblmForm tblmForm) {
        this.tblmForm = tblmForm;
    }


    public TblmFormManagement() {
    }



    public Long getPkid() {
        return this.pkid;
    }

    public void setPkid(Long pkid) {
        this.pkid = pkid;
    }

    public String getFormcode() {
        return this.formcode;
    }

    public void setFormcode(String formcode) {
        this.formcode = formcode;
    }

    public String getReportitem() {
        return this.reportitem;
    }

    public void setReportitem(String reportitem) {
        this.reportitem = reportitem;
    }

    public String getReportfield() {
        return this.reportfield;
    }

    public void setReportfield(String reportfield) {
        this.reportfield = reportfield;
    }

    // @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // @JoinColumn(name = "pkid")



}
```

iam getting error :

Exception encountered during context initialization -cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity.TblmForm.tblmFormManagement, referenced property unknown: com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity.TblmFormManagement.Mapping

any idea to solve for my problem? thank you

Comment: Just set your mappedBy to `tblmForm` like all online JPA docs would tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The @OneToOne mapping is wrong, the code works below with H2 test database:

```
@Table(name = "TBLM_FORM")
@Entity
public class TblmForm{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long pkid;

    // TAKE NOTE that form points to a property in the second entity TblmFormManagement
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "form")
    private TblmFormManagement tblmFormManagement;
}
```

Thus the second entity will be like this:

```
public class TblmFormManagement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long pkid;

    private String formcode;

    private String reportitem;

    private String reportfield;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_id", nullable=true)
    private TblmForm form;

}
```

Things to take note:

- The mappedBy at TblmForm.tblmFormManagement points to a Java property in TblmFormManagement
- The name of @JoinColumn at TblmFormManagement.form points to a database column of the table defined at TblmFormManagement

Hope the above pointers are useful to you.

Comment: on my database i dont have column form_id, where form_id taken?

Comment: The above is just an example, just make sure you got a database column for joining prupose.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
package com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity.TblmFormManagement;


    @Table(name = "TBLM_FORM")
    @Entity
    public class TblmForm{


        @Id
        private Long pkid;

        @Column(name = "FORMCODE")
        private String formcode;

        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="tblmForm")
        private TblmFormManagement tblmFormManagement;



        public TblmFormManagement getTblmFormManagement(){
            return tblmFormManagement;
        }

        public void setMapping(TblmFormManagement tblmFormManagement){
            this.tblmFormManagement=tblmFormManagement;
        }

       public Long getPkid() {
            return this.pkid;
        }

        public void setPkid(Long pkid) {
            this.pkid = pkid;
        }

        public String getFormcode() {
            return this.formcode;
        }

        public void setFormcode(String formcode) {
            this.formcode = formcode;
        }
```

.

```
package com.emerio.rnd.bali.oraclemongoservice.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name = "TBLM_FORMMANAGEMENT")
@Entity
public class TblmFormManagement{



    @Id
    private Long pkid;
    private String formcode;
    private String reportitem;
    private String reportfield;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pkid", nullable=true)
    private TblmForm tblmForm;


    public TblmForm getTblmForm() {
        return tblmForm;
    }

    public void setTblmForm(TblmForm tblmForm) {
        this.tblmForm = tblmForm;
    }


    public TblmFormManagement() {
    }



    public Long getPkid() {
        return this.pkid;
    }

    public void setPkid(Long pkid) {
        this.pkid = pkid;
    }

    public String getFormcode() {
        return this.formcode;
    }

    public void setFormcode(String formcode) {
        this.formcode = formcode;
    }

    public String getReportitem() {
        return this.reportitem;
    }

    public void setReportitem(String reportitem) {
        this.reportitem = reportitem;
    }

    public String getReportfield() {
        return this.reportfield;
    }

    public void setReportfield(String reportfield) {
        this.reportfield = reportfield;
    }

    // @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // @JoinColumn(name = "pkid")



}
```